# multiple requests in a single connection?

Tags: python, connection, httplib

Is it possible to put multiple requests without breaking the connection using python httplib?.
Like, can I upload a big file to the server in parts but in a single socket connection.

I looked for answers. But nothing seemed so clear and definite.

Any examples/related links will be helpfull.
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, the connection stays open until you close it using the `close()` method.

The following example, taken from the [httplib documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/httplib.html), shows how to perform multiple requests using a single connection:

```
>>> import httplib
>>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.python.org")
>>> conn.request("GET", "/index.html")
>>> r1 = conn.getresponse()
>>> print r1.status, r1.reason
200 OK
>>> data1 = r1.read()
>>> conn.request("GET", "/parrot.spam")
>>> r2 = conn.getresponse()
>>> print r2.status, r2.reason
404 Not Found
>>> data2 = r2.read()
>>> conn.close()
```

Comment: would you mind looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18221809/sending-a-few-requests-using-one-connection

Comment: For python 3, replace httplib with http.client

Answer (score 2):

You need to be sure to call the .read() function on your response. Otherwise you'll get an error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    conn.request("GET", "/2.html")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 955, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 983, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 853, in putrequest
    raise CannotSendRequest()
CannotSendRequest
```

This exception is raised if the return data has not been read (even if no data is returned, or an HTTP error was recieved [a 404 for example]).