# Single Persistent Connection or Multiple disposable sql connection for Enterprise applications

Tags: sql, database-connection, enterprise, sqlconnection

related:[Multiple Queries on single connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1906151/multiple-requests-in-a-single-connection)

In a Enterprise application, Is having a single connection execute for different inputs is better than disposing connections after their every execution? btw this is .net 2.0 and Sql 2005 i am talking about but the question applies to all database systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally better to just open and dispose connections when you need them. Let connection pooling do its job.

Comment: you got any references to why ?

Comment: Here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877692/passing-around-a-sqlconnection/2878449#2878449